# SVN login access prompt in SVN::Client

Tags: perl, svn

```
use SVN::Client;
my $ctx = new SVN::Client(
      auth => [SVN::Client::get_simple_provider(),
      SVN::Client::get_simple_prompt_provider(\&simple_prompt,2),
      SVN::Client::get_username_provider()]
      );

$ctx->cat(\*STDOUT, 'http://mysvn.repo.com/www/xxx','HEAD');

sub simple_prompt {
  my $cred = shift;
  my $realm = shift;
  my $default_username = shift;
  my $may_save = shift;
  my $pool = shift;

  print "Enter authentication info for realm: $realm\n";
  print "Username: ";
  my $username = <>;
  chomp($username);
  $cred->username($username);
  print "Password: ";
  my $password = <>;
  chomp($password);
  $cred->password($password);
}
```

**Problem**

After first login, SVN is caching the credentials and not prompting me to enter the authentication again. I enabled certain entries in the `config` & `servers` file to disable caching. But it did not work.

One more thing:
I installed `SVN::Client` using `CPAN` and installed `svn/apache` libraries using `apt-get`. I do not know which SVN is used by the perl module.

The config which I changed is of the SVN which I installed fresh later.

Can someone please let me know how to solve this?
I want the perl script to prompt for credentials always.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://search.cpan.org/~mlanier/Alien-SVN-1.6.12.0/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Client.pm):

> The functions that return the svn_auth_provider_object_t for prompt
>   style providers take a reference to a Perl subroutine to use for the
>   callback. The first parameter each of these subroutines receive is a
>   credential object. ... These functions and credential objects
>   always have a may_save member which specifies if the authentication
>   data will be cached.

So, I guess in implementation of your callback you need to have setting of **$may_save**:

```
$cred->may_save(0);
```

Or with user interaction as described [here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CLKAO/SVK-v2.2.2/lib/SVK/Config.pm):

```
print(
        $may_save
            ? "(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? "
            : "(R)eject or accept (t)emporarily? "
    );

    my $choice = lc(substr(<STDIN> || 'R', 0, 1));

    if ($choice eq 't') {
        $cred->may_save(0);
    }
    elsif ($may_save and $choice eq 'p') {
        $cred->may_save(1);
    }
```